# Will the KL divergence between two distributions decrease after passing the fixed channel?

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory

Suppose there are two continuous distributions whose pdfs are $p_1$ and $p_2$, defined on a common support $\mathcal{X}$. Suppose that there is a conditional pdf (the channel) $M:\mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Two pdfs $q_1$ and $q_2$ are generated from $p_1$ and $p_2$ by passing $M$. To be more precise,

$q_1(y)=\int p_1(x)M(y|x) dx$,

$q_2(y)=\int p_2(x)M(y|x) dx$.

My question is: Does the following inequality

$D(q_1||q_2)\leq D(p_1||p_2)$

always hold? $D$ denotes the KL divergence.

Comment: Yes, this is the data processing inequality.

Comment: I don't immediately see how to apply the data processing inequality here, but it sure feels similar. jkds, can you say if something goes wrong with a direct proof (plugging in for $q_1,q_2$)?

Comment: @usul The data processing inequality for mutual information is much easier to prove. However, now we need to prove the inequality for KL divergence.

Comment: http://www.stat.yale.edu/~yw562/teaching/598/lec04.pdf The proof is here. Thanks.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Yes. This is indeed the data processing inequality.

Answer (score 1):

As Alf [said](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460704/will-the-kl-divergence-between-two-distributions-decrease-after-passing-the-fixe#comment1194774_460704), this is the data processing inequality -- see e.g. [Theorem 7.2](https://people.lids.mit.edu/yp/homepage/data/LN_fdiv.pdf).

Comment: I have checked. Yes, it is data processing inequality. Thanks

Comment: @jkfds : All right. If you are satisfied with the answer, then [these guidelines](https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers) may be relevant here.